# Pad a Number with Leading Zeros via Text Box TextChanged event

Tags: c#, .net

I have .`Net` application with simple `text box` that the user need to add number with up to 15 digits.
If the number Length is less 15 i want to add before the input number Leading Zeros.
For example if the user insert the number `1002` i want the `text box` auto add `000000000001002` so i try to to that via my `text box` `TextChanged event`:

```
private void radTextBoxNum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "";
    if (radTextBoxNum.Text.Length < 15)
    {
        int currentlength = radTextBoxNum.Text.Length;
        int addZeroes = 15 - radTextBoxNum.Text.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < addZeroes; i++)
        {
            str += "0";
        }
    }

    string val = radTextBoxNum.Text;
    radTextBoxNum.Text = "";
    radTextBoxNum.Text = str + val;
}
```

So my problem is that after insert one number i got this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: The event handler changes the text in the text box, so it triggers itself infinitely until the stock overflows, i.e. you cant change the text of a TextBox within its TextChanged event handler.

Comment: So i can i do that automatically while the user type numbers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do this in the TextChanged event, as long as you prevent the changes that happen inside the event from calling the event again, which is what caused your StackOverflowException.

```
private void radTextBoxNum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  radTextBoxNum.TextChanged -= radTextBoxNum_TextChanged;
  string text = radTextBoxNum.Text.TrimStart('0');
  radTextBoxNum.Text = text.PadLeft(15, '0');
  radTextBoxNum.Select(radTextBoxNum.TextLength, 0);
  radTextBoxNum.TextChanged += radTextBoxNum_TextChanged;
}
```

Instead of removing and adding the handler, you could accomplish this with a simple form level variable.  Also, it would be better to place the code in a Try...Catch...Finally where you would add the handler back in the Finally block, just as a precaution against something going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your text length is continuously changing, and thus `int addZeroes = 15 - radTextBoxNum.Text.Length` is continuously increasing.

You'll continue to run into issues if you use the `TextChanged` event.  Try using the `Validated` event instead (when the field is exited):

```
private void radTextBoxNum_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radTextBoxNum.Text = radTextBoxNum.Text.PadLeft(15, '0');
}
```

Comment: Could change the while loop into a String.PadLeft(15, '0'). Looping string operations are costly.

Comment: Could use `radTextBoxNum.Text = newValue.PadLeft(15, '0');`

Comment: Never new about `String.PadLeft()`.

Comment: @muddymess -- but I suspect `String.PadLeft()` loops under the hood, albeit with a string builder.

Comment: @roryap Quite possibly, but then you could still use it for readabilities sake.

Comment: @muddymess -- agreed.